# WPF .Net 6 Windows ClickOnce application: activation arguments not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, arguments, app-startup

I have a WPF app built with .Net 6.0 and deployed with ClickOnce as an offline-only application.
I set a file association in my manifest file:

```
<fileAssociation
xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1"
extension=".customext"
description="Custom File"
progid="0"
defaultIcon="AppIcon.ico"/>
```

When i deploy and install the application, the app is working fine and firing up when double-clicking a .customext file.

I need to read the file content, so I subscribed the **Startup** event in **App.xaml**:

```
Startup="Application_Startup"
```

Then, in App.xaml.cs:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow mainWindow = new();
    foreach (string s in e.Args)
    {
        // Here I need to manage the file content
    }
    mainWindow.Show();
}
```

The problem is **e.Args** is always empty.

What I tried:

1. Using `Environment.GetCommandLineArguments()`
2. Overriding `OnStartup` event in App.xaml.cs

I previously got this working but it was a Net Framework application, so probably there's something different I'm not taking into account.

What am I doing wrong? I googled looking for solutions but most of the answers are Net Framework-realated and use the **ActivationArguments** class (solution not available in .Net Core).

Answer (score 0):

Step-1:
   Update the VS2022 to the lastest version.
Step-2:
  Project RightClick => Publish => Publish-Tab => Show All => Setting-tab => Options => Allow Url-Paramaters....
Step-3:
  Copy [this file](https://github.com/simmotech/Net6ClickOnce/blob/master/ClickOnceCommandLineTestApp/ClickOnceInfo.cs) code to you app.
Step-4:
  Write Fllowing code:

```
var clickOnceInfo = new ClickOnceInfo();
    if (!clickOnceInfo.IsNetworkDeployed)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(" app only can be start from Web Page,cant't direct start app");
        return;
    }
    var query = clickOnceInfo.ActivationUri?.Query ?? "QueryEMPTY";
    if (query == "QueryEMPTY")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("paramater empty,can't start app");
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, please can you translate strings to English?

Comment: @PrivateFrank im update the strings.in my app,finaly im use the .application only to setup and update,im use URL Protocol to call the local app to startup.